# How do I display country name and population when I hover over world map using Python folium library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tooltip, geojson, folium

I made a Webmap with python using folium. The map reads in *population.json* file that contains country names, and population number and displays a map on browser.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas
import folium

map = folium.Map(location=[32, 0], zoom_start=4.3, tiles = "CartoDB positron", max_zoom = 100)


fgp = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Population" )

def colorPicker(population):
    if population < 10000000:
        return 'green'
    elif population >= 10000000 and population < 500000000:
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'


fgp.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('population.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read(), 
style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': colorPicker(x['properties']['POP2005'])},
tooltip=lambda x: '%s\n%s' % (x['properties']['Name'], x['properties']['POP2005'])

))


map.add_child(fgp)

map.save("index.html")
```

I created feature group and add_child to add colors to each country on the map based on their population size using this code:

```
style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': colorPicker(x['properties']['POP2005'])}
```

What I wanted to then is whenever user hovers over a country, I want to display the name of the country and the population size of the country. For that, I wrote:

```
tooltip=lambda x: '%s\n%s' % (x['properties']['Name'], x['properties']['POP2005'])
```

Instead of giving me the name of the country, it gives me this...
[Picture of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAZnM.png)

It suppose to say "China: 'population size'", but instead is shows "at 0x24...."

I'm not sure why. I've tried several variations of tooltip such as:

```
tooltip=lambda x: '{0}\n{1}'.format(x['properties']['Name'], x['properties']['POP2005']) 
tooltip=lambda x: '%s\n%s' % (x['properties']['Name'], x['properties']['POP2005']) 
tooltip= lambda x: {'text': x['properties']['Name']}))
tooltip= lambda x: {'%s': x['properties']['Name']}))
```

But still, shows me same output

Here's link to population.json file: [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7-QNyf2NVdad4xH3AVkQ48yUJ-CHVvX/view)

Comment: Please provide `population.json` file. Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7-QNyf2NVdad4xH3AVkQ48yUJ-CHVvX/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GeoJson`](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/features.py#L322) and [`GeoJsonTooltip`](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/folium/features.py#L907) classes:

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[32, 0],
               zoom_start=4.3,
               tiles = "CartoDB positron",
               max_zoom = 100)

def colorPicker(population):
    if population < 10000000:
        return 'green'
    elif population >= 10000000 and population < 500000000:
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'

folium.GeoJson(open('population.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read(),
               name = 'Population',
               style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': colorPicker(x['properties']['POP2005'])},
               tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=('NAME', 'POP2005',),
                                               aliases=('Country','Population')),
               show = True).add_to(m)


#folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

and you get:

[image]